# Tkinter is very slow while displaying database results

Tags: python, mysql, database, tkinter

I am trying to write an interface with Python which shows the result of a database search. I am using Mysql as db and Tkinter an gui. database has 1000s of row and depends of the search it filters the data and shows the appropriate ones. I am putting a sample of my code. I tested the query time by printind something to the console and for 600 data it takes less than 1 sec. Which is very good for me. But displaying the results takes 10 sec. n the result, I want all data displayed as text except the first column which should be a button. How can I make it display faster? Thanks in advance.
Here is a summarized version of my code:

```
# Values from search form
a = a.get()
b = b.get()
c = c.get()
d = d.get()
e = e.get()


find_query = f"""SELECT A, B, C, D, E FROM works WHERE A LIKE "%{a}%" AND B LIKE "%{b}%" AND C 
             LIKE "%{c}%" AND D LIKE "%{d}%" AND E LIKE "%{e}%"
              """
db_connect.cursor.execute(find_query)
result = db_connect.cursor.fetchall()
print (len(result)) # It writes here in less than 1 sec for 580 items

for i in range(len(result)):
    a_search = result[i][0]
    b_search = result[i][1]
    c_search = result[i][2]
    d_search = result[i][3]
    e_search = result[i][4]
    
    a_search_button = Button(result_frame, text=a_search, anchor="w", width=10, bd=0,                                                    
                             bg="white", padx=5, pady=3, command=lambda wnt=a_search: 
                             edit_work(a))
   a_search_button.grid(row=i + 1, column=0, sticky="w")
   b_search_label = Label(result_frame, text=b_search, anchor="w", width=10, bd=0, bg="white",
                                              padx=5, pady=5)
   b_search_label.grid(row=i + 1, column=1, sticky="w")
   .
   .
   .

# Displaying these 580 items takes 10 sec.
```

Comment: How long does the query take to execute in MySQL?

Comment: Are you connecting to a server with traffic or slow response time?

Comment: Use *pagination* instead.  I don't think you can see all the 580 rows at the same time.

Comment: MySQL response time is very fast. No problem at all. it is around 0.015 sec. in mysql workbench. And it is less than 1 sec. in python when I test it.

Comment: @acw1668, you are right. I will need pagination or will show a part of results and demand detailed search. But still I am curious why this tkinter module (or my code) responses very slow

Comment: Your code is actually creating 580x5 widgets, i.e. 2900 widgets.  So I don't think it is *very slow* (actually it takes around 0.2 seconds to create them and around 4 seconds to show them in my AMD Ryzen 4900H PC).

Comment: @acw1668 You are right. I might expect too much :) Thanks

Comment: Sounds like Tkinter is the slow part?